# Datastax Cassandra java driver cluster configurations

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a cluster with 3 servers and I am trying to create Datastax Cassandra Cluster with the following configuration. Should I leave it to Datastax default values or what are the recommended values?

```
failover.retryPolicy = ?
failover.reconnectionPolicyDelayMs = ?
pooling.coreConnectionsPerHost = ?
pooling.maxConnectionPerHost= ?
socket.keepAlive=?
socket.reuseAddress=?
socket.tcpNoDelay=?
socket.receiveBufferSize=?
socket.sendBufferSize=?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the defaults and it isn't working?

Comment: It is working with default values. Is it okay to use default values in prod?

Comment: Generally yes. You will usually have a specific reason to change from the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Cassandra and the DataStax drivers are shipping with pretty sane default configurations. I'd say you should start developing your application and turn to tuning the configuration only at the time you notice that your specific scenario and deployment setup require changes.